# How to dynamically add placeholders in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to add PlaceHolder in CKEditor , through javascript code.

I am having one list box besides of CKEditor. so when user select any question from list box and click a small arrow button, I wanted to add the selected question id as a placeholder in CKEditor.

So is there any way(or Javascript Function) by which i can add a placeholder to current cursor position in CKEditor just by passing a text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CKEDITOR.editor.insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) is what you are looking for:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.insertHtml( '[[foo]]' );
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the api to remove placeholder.

Comment: @PavanTiwari `editor.widgets.del( editor.widgets.instances[ ... ] )` should do the trick